# Issue with re-join same room after reconnect SocketIO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to understand why the following code doesn't work for some reason. Basically I want the same client to be able to rejoin the same room, but somehow when I print the list of clients in that room after this client reconnect, only this client shows up, the rests are not there???

#### Client

```
var id=null, socket = null;
var publicKey = null;
var first = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,8);
var last = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,8);
$('#bt1').click(function(){
    socket = io();
    socket.on('connect',function(){
        addText('Connect to server. First-Last '+ first +' '+last);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(data){          
        addText('Disconnect from server'); 
    });
    socket.on('verifyid_1',function(data){
        id = data.id;
        socket.emit('verifyid_2',{id:id,publicKey:publicKey})
        addText('ClientID '+id); 
    });
    socket.on('gamecreated',function(data){
        publicKey = data.publicKey;
        addText('PublicKey '+publicKey);
    });
    socket.on('playerrejoinroom',function(data){addText(JSON.stringify(data))});
});
$('#bt2').click(function(){ socket.connect();});
$('#bt3').click(function(){ socket.disconnect();});
$('#bt4').click(function(){
    publicKey = $('#input').val(); addText('PublicKey '+publicKey+' is entered');
    socket.emit('joinroom',{publicKey:publicKey});
});
$('#bt5').click(function(){
    addText('Create new game with clientID '+id);
    socket.emit('creategame',{id:id,NumberOfPlayers:5,UserInfo:{first:first,last:last}});
});
function addText(text){ // this juts logs to a chatbox on screen
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(text)); 
    $('#console').scrollTop($('#console').prop("scrollHeight"));
}
```

#### Server

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var id = socket.id;
    var publicKey = null;
    console.log('a user connected with id '+id);
    socket.emit('verifyid_1',{id:id});

    socket.on('verifyid_2',function(data){    
        if (id != data.id) {console.log('___Old client reconnects '+data.id);}
        console.log('___Double check '+id);
        if (util.isExists(data.publicKey)) { // this function just check if the obj exists or not
            socket.join(publicKey); // if publickey exists, this socket should join the previous room identified by publicKey
            listClientsInRoom(publicKey);
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user#'+id+' disconnected '+util.isExists(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[publicKey]));    
        if (!util.isExists(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[publicKey])) return;
        listClientsInRoom(publicKey);
    });
    socket.on('creategame',function(data){
        var owner = {id:data.id, first:data.UserInfo.first, last:data.UserInfo.last};
        var newpublicKey = controller.addGameSession(data.NumberOfPlayers,owner); 
        socket.join(newpublicKey); 
        publicKey = newpublicKey;
        socket.emit('gamecreated',{publicKey:publicKey});
    });

    socket.on('joinroom',function(data){
        console.log("Joinroom for client "+id+" to room: "+data.publicKey);
        socket.join(data.publicKey); publicKey = data.publicKey;
        listClientsInRoom(publicKey);      
    });
});
function listClientsInRoom(key){
  var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[key].sockets;
  console.log('___Clients in room:'+JSON.stringify(clients));
}
```

Output on server when I run with 3 clients:

```
a user connected with id /#mxZOL2Ibr9jrsMkiAAAA
___Double check /#mxZOL2Ibr9jrsMkiAAAA
a user connected with id /#oGt5s1ILXhp5tGy9AAAB
___Double check /#oGt5s1ILXhp5tGy9AAAB
a user connected with id /#59OZXN32hnBWzyDVAAAC
___Double check /#59OZXN32hnBWzyDVAAAC
Joinroom for client /#oGt5s1ILXhp5tGy9AAAB to room: m9xdowe7lxat088508
___Clients in room:{"/#mxZOL2Ibr9jrsMkiAAAA":true,"/#oGt5s1ILXhp5tGy9AAAB":true}
Joinroom for client /#59OZXN32hnBWzyDVAAAC to room: m9xdowe7lxat088508
___Clients in room:{"/#mxZOL2Ibr9jrsMkiAAAA":true,"/#oGt5s1ILXhp5tGy9AAAB":true,"/#59OZXN32hnBWzyDVAAAC":true}
user#/#59OZXN32hnBWzyDVAAAC disconnected true
___Clients in room:{"/#mxZOL2Ibr9jrsMkiAAAA":true,"/#oGt5s1ILXhp5tGy9AAAB":true}
a user connected with id /#m4k21oL_S493uVmpAAAD
___Double check /#m4k21oL_S493uVmpAAAD
___Clients in room:{"/#m4k21oL_S493uVmpAAAD":true}
```

#### What happened:

```
1. Connect 3 clients by hitting connect button (bt1).
2. Client1 create new game (button bt5). Save the publicKey locally.
3. Client2 and client3 use this publicKey to join the room (button bt4)
4. Client3 disconnect (button bt3).
5. Client3 reconnect (button bt2)
6. Only ID of client3 is shown in the room of publicKey ???
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that re-iterating the problem and my code helps me find where the issue is.....:

```
if (util.isExists(data.publicKey)) { 
    socket.join(data.publicKey); // publicKey is a local variable to a newly established socke
        // so when the client reconnect this variable should be null by default.
        // I should have used data.publicKey given by the client instead. My bad
    listClientsInRoom(data.publicKey);
}
```

Sorry. It works now.